# How to create a result from sql server with a summed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, correlated-subquery

Hello what I want is to write a query which will fetch me 3 column:-

1. nvarchar column1
2. integer Values column2
3. single cell of the summed column2

is it possible , I am getting the following error:-

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tablename.columnname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What is the correct procedure to get data in the format I wish to get.

**Edit**

Jaques' answer works but I dont get what I want. What I want is:

```
column 1 PID | column 2 SID | column 3 | column 4 | Column 5(Total of 4)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | 1            | ABC      | 125.00   | 985.00
2            | 2            | XYZ      | 420.00   |
3            | 3            | DEF      | 230.00   |
4            | 4            | GHI      | 210.00   |
```

Comment: please post your query here

Comment: I am unable to construct a query like that. But I do know its like associating a single row as to a set of rows.

Comment: I am unable to construct a query for it. But I do know its like associating a single row as to a set of rows. Here's the whole scenario :- I have table with columns 1,2,3,4 , I have to get a column of date from a different table on the left and a column total on the right. The target is to get a heading like -      Date, ABC,XYZ,DEF,GHI,Total. The columns names ABC,XYZ,DEF and GHI are rows in a different table . Please provide a solution.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I'm still not sure why you want to do this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way, because you need to add all non aggregated values in the group by, which makes it difficult

```
Select column1, column2, SUM(column2) OVER (PARTITION BY column1) as Total from [Table]
```

This should work.

You can do it with a subselect from your edited answer, but why do you want it like that?

```
Select Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, (Select SUM(Column4) from Table) as Column 5 from Table
```

Comment: No If I use the above query you mentioned I am getting a group by error - "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'tablename.columnname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Hi Jacques since you have been into programming I would like to have some advice on what to refer in order to learn the best practices for RDBMS and sql server and also the Best practices in ASP.NET development with C#. I keep learning new things but have been out of touch with the industry, Now that I am back to it, I find it weird that people are still using those old ADO.NET and layered approach when MVC is at hand to rescue, this makes me recollect all those and my pace at which I work is a lot slower. Could you please tell me what exactly is the current trend in .net development.

Comment: @user110246 you must type something wrong if you use the above mentioned query and execute it. Make sure that you have `( )` around the sub-select, otherwise you will get the error mentioned. To answer your second comment. In my opinion, MVC is just bloatware on existing technologies. You use what you feel works the best for you, and what helps you get the job done quicker. If that is MVC for you, then awesome. I'm not that much into ASP.NET, so maybe you should register on a Forum with other ASP.NET devs and discuss with them. Good luck

Comment: As you said the above trials I made didn't work , perhaps I am not clear with sql server. I am able to get the column list as comma separated values in a variable but again when it comes to adding up all those I don't know what to do. Can you suggest me how to add columns which are in a comma separate list inside a variable please.

Answer (score 1):

i suspect you are using some aggregate function on some columns and not listing your remaining columns in group by clause. your query should look like this.

```
select sum(column2), column1 from table1
group by column1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include the same columns in the `select` and `group by` clauses.

If you want to sum a column with all the values, you must include in the select clause a column with different value for each row, like this:

```
SELECT columnId, sum(column4) as total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY columnId
```

or simply don't include on the select any extra column, like this:

```
select sum(column4) from MyTable
```

Comment: Hi Jacques I have done it with the help of pivot and temporary tables. May be it will cost me performance but it works